# Error when trying to install googleapiclient in my Python Project

Tags: python, pycharm, google-api-client, google-api-python-client

I use this import to import the googleapiclient in my Python project...

import googleapiclient.discovery

when I try to install the package, I get this error

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement googleapiclient (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for googleapiclient
WARNING: You are using pip version 21.3.1; however, version 23.0 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'C:....\venv\Scripts\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

I upgraded my pip version and it says I have the 23.0 installed but somehow it is not applying for the Project I think. Can someone help me how it should work?

[image]

Comment: Do you try `pip install google-api-python-client` ? 
edit: Because I think that you try  `pip install googleapiclient`

Comment: Yeah I also tried it, it installed something and when I run it again, it says "Requirement already satisfied " for all the stuff that would be installed. Somehow the project still doesn't realise I already installed the stuff